# Adding a controller into a c# RestAPI to forward request and response in two directions inside http actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have two already existing C# RestAPIs **A** and **B**. Clients are communicating with both A and B via HTTP requests and vice versa. Due to some network reasons B won't be reachable to and from the Clients.

The task is to add a Controller to A, who can still communicate with the Clients and B, to forward every request and response from the Clients to B and vice versa **(Client ⇆ A ⇆ B)**. A needs to be able to forward every HTTP method (GET, POST, ...) and file or body the same way it received. Also headers, body, authentification etc. needs to be the same. This means that the outgoing request out of A needs to be identical to the incoming request. After forwarding the request A also needs to be able to forward the response (with the same response code, etc.) of either B or one of the Clients in the opposite direction.

This is what I have so far:

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class TestAController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{name:nonapi}/{backEnd}/{*urlSuffix}")]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PingGet(string name, string backEnd, string urlSuffix)
    {
        string ip = "";
        string port ="";

        //Do some stuff here to get IP and port of receiver out of the routing

        Request.Headers.Remove("Host");
        Request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://" + ip + port + "/api/test/ping");
        Request.Content = null;

        var client = new HttpClient();
        return client.SendAsync(Request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{name:nonapi}/{backEnd}/{*urlSuffix}")]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PingPost(string name, string backEnd, string urlSuffix, [FromBody] string body)
    {
        string ip = "";
        string port ="";

        //Do some stuff here to get IP and port of receiver out of the routing

        Request.Headers.Remove("Host");
        Request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://" + ip + port + "/api/test/ping");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        return client.SendAsync(Request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    }
}
```

Testing with Insomnia, HTTP GET seems to work, but when I try to send a HTTP POST with a simple text as a body it doesn't work. Insomnia tells me that i am getting a HTTPRequestException.
Please help me to solve this problem and to add the functions for the remaining HTTP methods if they should differ. I'm pretty new to ASP.NET.

Comment: It is trying to realize a low-level task with high-level programming. If you are running your applications on IIS7 or later, try [using IIS as a reverse proxy](https://tecadmin.net/set-up-reverse-proxy-using-iis/)

Comment: This doesn’t solve my problem since your way I need to do this confit for each port. But A is determining the IP and the port of B depending on the route requested by the client. For example a client requests HTTP GET localhost:XXXX/nameOfClient/service/...    In this case A compares the name and the service with a file and gets the ip and the port from B. Which means I have multiple ports to forward to and I can’t do the settings for the reverse proxy for each service possibly requested by a client.